# Page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at inline (“default-src”). Unable to revert config changes

Tags: firefox, content-security-policy

[Here is an image to show better the network tab and console details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qI0lL.png)

I inadvertently clicked a few wrong buttons and now my Content-Security Policy has changed and I am unable to make any GET calls on localhost. It refuses to load any information at all.

I have tried to find a solution but nothing seems to work.

I am using the Firefox browser. I can provide further information. However, I am stuck at this point with these changes.

[The following are my current Content Security Policy settings.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XJBmt.png)

Comment: As I understand from your post you only have this issue in Firefox?

Comment: Dear @MaxVisser, no, I am not sure if it was specific to Firefox only.
However, I went ahead and reset my browser settings to default and that seems to have done the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was *something* wrong that I couldn't figure out so I reset my Firefox settings to default and that has resolved the situation.